# Html/css keyframe transition not working in IE and Firefox properly

Tags: html, css-transitions, css-animations, keyframe

I want to create a banner with 6 frames, without the css stylesheet and use only style tags in html.

I posted the 3rd and 4th since they are different and that can be seen.

My problem is that in firefox it stops on the 4th(1-2-3-4-4-4) frame and doesn't continue to the 5th and 6th and in IE i can see only the 1st,2nd and it jumps to the 5th frame.

3rd frame

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:120px;top:0px; left:0px;  position:absolute; animation: frame3-animation 30s infinite ease-in;">
<img src="img/background2.jpg" style="position: absolute;   top:0px;    left:0px;    " alt="">
<img src="img/white_background.png" style="position: absolute;  top:10px;   left:36px;   " alt="">
<img src="img/logo2.png" style="top:7px;    left:18px;  position: absolute;   background-position: center;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" alt="">
<img src="img/frame3_cat_traiesti.png" style="position: absolute; top:20px; left:355px; " alt="">
    <style>@-webkit-keyframes frame3-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
48%  { opacity:1;}
49%  {opacity:0;}
99%  {opacity:0;}
99.99999%  {opacity:0;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-moz-keyframes frame3-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
48%  { opacity:1;}
49%  {opacity:0;}
99%  {opacity:0;}
99.99999%  {opacity:0;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-oz-keyframes frame3-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
48%  { opacity:1;}
49%  {opacity:0;}
99%  {opacity:0;}
99.99999%  {opacity:0;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-ms-keyframes frame3-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
48%  { opacity:1;}
49%  {opacity:0;}
99%  {opacity:0;}
99.99999%  {opacity:0;}
    }</style>
```

This is the 4th frame.
I used z-index in the animation because it has the clickable button and without z-index it just wouldn't be clickable

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:120px; top:0px; left:0px; position:absolute; animation: frame4-animation 30s infinite ease-in;">
<img src="img/background2.jpg" style="position: absolute;   top:0px;    left:0px;   overflow: visible;" alt="">
<img src="img/white_background2.png" style="position: absolute; top:8px;    left:35px;  overflow: visible;" alt="">
<img src="img/frame4_cat_traiesti.png" style="position: absolute;   top:30px;   left:140px; overflow: visible;" alt="">
<img src="img/frame4_circle.png" style="position: absolute; top:11px;   left:470px; overflow: visible;" alt="">
<img src="img/frame4_1x.png" style="position: absolute; top:17px;   left:596px; overflow: visible;" alt="">
<img src="img/logo2.png" style="position: absolute; top:7px;    left:18px;  overflow: visible; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;" alt="">
<a href="INSERT LINK" target="_blank" style="position: absolute;    top:44px;   left:768px; "><img src="img/promotie.png" style="overflow: visible;" alt=""></a><!-- Insert Link-->
    <style>@-webkit-keyframes frame4-animation {
0%   {opacity:1;}
65%  {opacity:1;}
66%  {z-index:2;}
99%  {z-index:2;}
99.99999%  {z-index:2;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-moz-keyframes frame4-animation {
0%   {opacity:1;}
65%  {opacity:1;}
66%  {z-index:2;}
99%  {z-index:2;}
99.99999%  {z-index:2;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-oz-keyframes frame4-animation {
0%   {opacity:1;}
65%  {opacity:1;}
66%  {z-index:2;}
99%  {z-index:2;}
99.99999%  {z-index:2;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-ms-keyframes frame4-animation {
0%   {opacity:1;}
65%  {opacity:1;}
66%  {z-index:2;}
99%  {z-index:2;}
99.99999%  {z-index:2;}
    }</style>
```

And this is the style from 5th frame (to see the difference from the 4th)

```
        <style>@-webkit-keyframes frame5-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
81%  { opacity:1;}
82%  {z-index:9;}
99%  {z-index:9;}
99.99999%  {z-index:9;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-moz-keyframes frame5-animation {
    0%   { opacity:1;}
81%  { opacity:1;}
82%  {z-index:9;}
99%  {z-index:9;}
99.99999%  {z-index:9;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-oz-keyframes frame5-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
81%  { opacity:1;}
82%  {z-index:9;}
99%  {z-index:9;}
99.99999%  {z-index:9;}
    }</style>
    <style>@-ms-keyframes frame5-animation {
0%   { opacity:1;}
81%  { opacity:1;}
82%  {z-index:9;}
99%  {z-index:9;}
99.99999%  {z-index:9;}
    }</style>
```

Plus I'd like to have smoother transitions.
The first 3 go quite smooth, but are slower that I'd like and 4-6 are instant transitions. I'd like to have "a middle way" between these 2.

1-3 style transition are the same, 4-5 can be seen and the 6 has just a higher index than 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your jsfiddles in here so others can see them if they come over the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How does keyframe animation work?

Animation short hand:
`animation: NAME, DURATION, TIMING-FUNCTION, DELAY, ITERATIONCOUNT, DIRECTION, FILL-MODE, PLAY-STATE`

Your animation:
`animation: frame3-animation 30s infinite ease-in;`
`frame3-animation` = `NAME`
`30s` = `DURATION`
`infinite` = `ITERATION-COUNT`
`ease-in` = `TIMING-FUNCTION`

## Your questions

#### (eg. What you demand in your question)

> Plus I'd like to have smoother transitions.

I do not know what you consider smoother transitions.
What do you want to transition?
What keyframe/frame are you talking about?
What do you consider to be a smooth transition?

> The first 3 go quite smooth, but are slower that I'd like

**This i can help you with**:
If you want a keyframe animation to go faster set a shorter duration on the keyframe:

```
animation: NAME DURATION ITERATIONCOUNT; 
animation: frame3-animation 5s infinite ease-in;
animation: frame3-animation 2s infinite ease-in;
etc.
```

> 4-6 are instant transitions.  I'd like to have "a middle way" between these 2.

Then you have to set the DURATION of the animation larger then 0s to avoid getting an instant transition and smaller then 30s.

### What I'm guessing your having problems with

You are using z-index in keyframe-animation and opacity,
So my guess is that you are animating some element to appear and disappear.

When using the z-index in a animation it will happen instantly.

```css
.frame {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px dotted pink;
  padding: 50px;
}
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.red {
  left: 10%;
  background-color: red;
  animation: shuffle 2s infinite;
}
.blue {
  left: -10%;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: shuffle2 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes shuffle {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
  }
}
@keyframes shuffle2 {
  0% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="bubble red"></div>
  <div class="bubble blue"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above i adjusted the keyframe so that exactly when the red circle becomes transparent the z-index changes. When this is done you can see that the blue circle jumps behind the red one.
And having the z-index higher will make it clickable eg. pointer-events will work on the element.

**For future reference here are some points from [How do i ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):**

- Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program!
- If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so

Comment: Thanks a lot for your entire answer. I'll try it as soon as I get to my PC

But about Firefox and IE, do you know why they're not working properly?
And also, the button in frame4 isn't working in Firefox.
Could it be the z-index in the animation for both problems??

About the transitions, is just that I'm trying to find a "sweet-spot" for it.
Since one transition was too slow and the other one was too fast.

Comment: Unless you narrow down your code, or give me an working example. Its hard for me to help you out. 
There could be errors with IE and FireFox, and i would be happy to test it for you, but you have not given any runnable code.
I can't think my way to and answer when it comes to browser support unfortunalty.

Comment: Thats the code is used. Those are my req. Banner with without html,head,body,css. Just to use the style tag.The only thing missing from here are the pictures for img/ .
If you use frame 3 and 4 you can test it. I don't know how to replace those in an actual running code.
White background is lie 2/3 of the background and in the 4th frame the button is on the right side something like 100x50px size and the rest are just images. Starting from the left side one after another until the a href, which is the last button (like in a row)

Comment: @MichaelM There seems to be a couple of things your wondering about. 
Go to http://www.jsfiddle.net and paste in your code there. If you create a working example of your problems (NOT YOUR CODE PASTED) just the parts that are not working, I'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll be back in about 3,5h with a working example. Let me know if you'll be able to help me then or now, to know if I should make it or not.

Comment: @MichaelM you can allways find me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs 
I'm on every day, but you will need 25 rep or some thing like that to talk there. So you just have to upvote some questions, get a tiny bit of reputation and you can ask my anything there :P

Comment: I will start getting more active...but I have about 6h left to fix this...that's why I was asking if you'll be able to help me in about 3,5h, to know if I should me a working example or not.
Thanks for letting me know where I should look for you :)

Comment: I just made a working one. http://jsfiddle.net/Lpqa6Lxn/
Open it in firefox or IE and you'll see that in firefox it won't change from frame 4 to 5, can't click on ahref and in IE it's even worse. (in chrome and opera is working fine)
In chrome the transitions are different from firefox.

Comment: @MichaelM i had a really hard time reading your code since all styles are inline or in mutliple style tags. You should ATLEAST put all styles in one <style> tag. Anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/fjtsytmk/4/ <- This works in the newest version IE, FireFox and Chrome. Hope you can learn something from the fiddle i used more time on it then i would like.

Comment: Thanks. Only with opacity it work fine, but I had to use z-index, else the link button wouldn't have the option to be clicked. And the transition from 1 to 2 is instant and I'd like to make it smoother.